# VBA pulling data from table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large table that I've defined as "WW60_STRI" in the name manager of excel

I'm trying to write a function that returns the max number in column 1 of the table. Is below the correct syntax to use because I'm getting #value! as result when typing =wlookup(WW60_STRI,"maxdepth") into a cell

```
Public Function wlookup(Name As String, Retrieve As String)
Set WW60_STRI = Range("WW60_STRI")
Select Case Name
        Case WW60_STRI:
            Select Case Retrieve
                Case "maxdepth"
                    wlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(WW60_STRI.Columns(1))
            End Select
        Case Else
            wlookup = "error"
        End Select
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WW60_STRI` needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
Public Function wlookup(Name As String, Retrieve As String)
    Set WW60_STRI = Range("WW60_STRI")
    Select Case Name
        Case "WW60_STRI":
            Select Case Retrieve
                Case "maxdepth"
                    wlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(WW60_STRI.Columns(1))
            End Select
        Case Else
            wlookup = "error"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: thanks. looks like I should be using quotes in the cell also:
=wlookup("WW60_STRI","maxdepth")